# Is it possible to create an object with different values determined by the id of the object?

Tags: javascript, html, file

So I have some information fra a .csv file that I want to present in my web page. So far I have `var lines` which is a long string of information from each column in the csv file separated by `;`. Then I do some loops to get the elements I want:

```
           `for (var i = lines.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var row = lines[i];                 
                var header = lines[i].toString().split(":");                    
                var elements = header[1].toString().split(";");              
                for (var j =0; j <= elements.length - 1; j++) {
                    console.log(elements[j]);
                };               
            };`
```

When I print this to console I get something like this for each column:

```
Id: 2
Description: Loung paa selskapssiden
With: Spiller
Where: Samfundet - Selskapssiden
Date: 06.02.2014
Time: 23.00
```

Which is what I want. Now, I want to add this information to an object or whatever. How do I do that?
Is it possible to add it to an object so that I can get the information by doing a object call like:

```
information.id.description
```

where I do a `for` loop on the `.id`? Or is there an easier way storing and getting the information? Perhaps some jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just created a `var list=[]`, removed the last `for` loop, and added this code:

```
eventlist.push({id: elements[0], name: elements[1], description: elements[2], where: elements[3], date: elements[4], time: elements[5]});
```

Then I can look up the information by calling `list[0].id` `list[1].description` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Id as a key in the object, like this

```
var information = {};

for (var i = lines.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var row = lines[i];                 
    var header = lines[i].toString().split(":");                    
    var elements = header[1].toString().split(";");              

    for (var j =0; j <= elements.length - 1; j++) {
         information[elements[j].Id] = elements[j];
    }
};
```

Then you can look it up later with

```
information[2].Description
//          ^^ the Id property
```

Comment: The '.description' makes the output undefined. The same with just 'information[2]'. How do I add value to the properties like '.description' ?